# How to login into a website without using sendkeys?

Tags: excel, vba

I’m trying to login into this website without using sendkeys
https://terranovaeng.sienge.com.br/sienge/
But, seems this website wants to me to type my login and password.
Here is my code:

```
    Dim Usuário As String
    Dim Login As String

    Usuário = "My User"
    Password = "My password"

'OPEN INTERNET EXPLORER
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True


'NAVIGATE TO PAGE
    IE.Navigate "https://terranovaeng.sienge.com.br/sienge/"
    'IDENTIFICA SE O SIENGE FOI TOTALMENTE CARREGADO
    While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Wend
    sng = Timer
        Do While sng + 5 > Timer
        Loop

    'SEND MY USER NAME
    IE.Document.getElementById("linkslogin").Focus
    SendKeys  “Usuário”
    SendKeys "{tab}", True
    'IDENTIFICA SE O SIENGE FOI TOTALMENTE CARREGADO
    While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Wend
    sng = Timer
        Do While sng + 3 > Timer
        Loop

    'SEND MY PASSWORD 
    SendKeys  “Login”
    SendKeys "{tab}", True
    'IDENTIFICA SE O SIENGE FOI TOTALMENTE CARREGADO
    While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Wend
    sng = Timer
        Do While sng + 3 > Timer
        Loop

    'CLICK EM ENTRAR
    IE.Document.all("pbEnviar").form.all("pbEnviar").Click
    While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Wend
    sng = Timer
        Do While sng + 10 > Timer
        Loop


End sub
```

I trying using: getelementbyid, getelementbyclassname, fire event fuction and so on but it's not working. Is there Any awy to it without using sendkeys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this works

```
ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")(2).Value = "username"
ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")(3).Value = "password"
ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")(5).Click
```

or like this

```
dim aaa as object
set aaa = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")

aaa(2).Value = "username"
aaa(3).Value = "password"
aaa(5).Click
```

Comment: jsotola this is absolutely great.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full code for those who need:

```
Sub Login()

On Error GoTo Sair
```

'to refer to the running copy of Internet Explorer

```
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
'to refer to the HTML document returned
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Dim Usuário As String
Dim Login As String
Dim QuestionFieldLinks As IHTMLElementCollection

Usuário = Sheets("Ajustes").Range("E9").Value
Login = Sheets("Ajustes").Range("E11").Value

'open Internet Explorer in memory, and go to website
Set IE = New InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "https://terranovaeng.sienge.com.br/sienge/"
Do While IE.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Application.StatusBar = "Criando Conecção com Sienge..."
    DoEvents
Loop
    'IDENTIFICA SE O SIENGE FOI TOTALMENTE CARREGADO
    While IE.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Wend
    sng = Timer
        Do While sng + 2 > Timer
        Loop
```

'show text of HTML document returned

```
Set html = IE.Document
'Reset status bar
Application.StatusBar = ""
```

'INFORMA O NOME DO USUÁRIO

```
 IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")(1).Value = Usuário
   'IDENTIFICA SE O SIENGE FOI TOTALMENTE CARREGADO
    Do While IE.Busy = True
        DoEvents
    Loop
```

'PEGA O NOME CORRETO DO USUÁRIO NO SERVIDOR DO SIENGE

```
 ' Call IE.Document.parentWindow.execScript("pegarUsernameCorreto(this.id);", "JavaScript")

   'IDENTIFICA SE O SIENGE FOI TOTALMENTE CARREGADO
    While IE.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Wend
    sng = Timer
        Do While sng + 1 > Timer
        Loop
```

'INFORMA A SENHA DO USUÁRIO

```
IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")(2).Focus
   IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")(2).Value = Login

   IE.Document.all("submit").form.all("submit").Click
   'IDENTIFICA SE O SIENGE FOI TOTALMENTE CARREGADO
    Do While IE.Busy = True
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Application.StatusBar = "Conectado com o Sienge ..."
```

Sair:
'CONSULTA SE O USUÁRIO TEM CONECÇÃO ATIVA

```
'IDENTIFICA SE O SIENGE FOI TOTALMENTE CARREGADO

    Set elems = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")
                For Each e In elems
                    If e.innerText Like "Prosseguir" Then
                    IE.Navigate "https://terranovaeng.sienge.com.br/sienge/removerUsuarioLogadoServlet?acao=S"
                Exit Sub
            Else
        Exit For
    End If
    Next e
     'IDENTIFICA SE O SIENGE FOI TOTALMENTE CARREGADO
    Do While IE.Busy = True
        DoEvents
    Loop
```

'MsgBox "Ok, Conectado com o Sienge.", vbInformation, "SiengeXLS - Login"
Application.StatusBar = "Conectado com o Sienge ..."

```
'MSGBOX
    Set ele = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("p")
    For Each e In ele
    If e.innerText Like "O número de sessões de usuários simultâneos atingiu o limite contratado." Then
    IE.Visible = False
    'MsgBox "Ok, Conectado com o Sienge.", vbInformation, "SiengeXLS - Login"
    Application.StatusBar = "O número de sessões de usuários simultâneos atingiu o limite contratado."
    IE.Quit
    Exit Sub
    End If
    Next e

End Sub
```